# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2}\sin x)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

I'm trying to answer this having been sent a photo of the questions from someone doing A level Edexcel Maths and I'm struggling. Any advice would be appreciated.

Evaluate and justify the validity of your answer (2 marks) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right)^n $$

My attempts so far:

When $n = 0$

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right)^n = 1$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$$

so:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\sin x\right)^n - 1 = \frac{1}{1- \frac{1}{2}\sin x} -1 = \frac{2}{2-\sin x}-1 = \frac{\sin x}{2-\sin x}$$

As far as I can see it seems to converge to between $-\frac{1}{3}$ and 1 depending on $x$.
Is that it? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Great thank you! I though I was going insane, was expecting it to come out to a specific number.

Comment: Slightly simpler to use $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a r^n = ar/(1-r)$.

Comment: @RobPratt Ah yes of course! and thank you for editing it to look better.